# How do I get my options to display with Autocomplete (MUI)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to help my friend figure out why Autocomplete isn't showing anything.
Below is the code:

```
var names = [];
const schoolList = async () => ( await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/grabUnivNames/")
    .then((res) => {

      // schoolList =  JSON.stringify(res.data.msg)
      names = res.data.msg.map(user => user.school_name);;
      console.log(names)
      // return res.data.msg.map(user => user.school_name);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("ERROR");
      console.log(error);
    })
  );
schoolList();
```

return() with Autocomplete:

```
        <Autocomplete
            options={names}
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="School Name" />}
          />
```

What `names` contains:

[image]

What shows:

[image]

I only started learning about Autocomplete today but I think the problem may be in how he is obtaining `names` or how `names` is formatted but I am also very unfamiliar with Autocomplete.

How can I get `names` to display on the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all i am assuming that your data fetching is done correctly and you use react [functional based components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components).
You will need 2 main requirements to achieve what you want

1. first of all replace normal variable **names** with [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) hook of
   **names** array and **loading** boolean, cause normal variables will not have dynamic values over multiple renders
2. MUI Autocomplete supports [async](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#load-on-open) operation , so you will attach the getSchoolList handler to onOpen prop, and loading prop so let the component show progress while loading

```js
const [names,setNames] = React.useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false)
const getSchoolList = () => {
setLoading(true)
axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/grabUnivNames/")
    .then((res) => {

      // schoolList =  JSON.stringify(res.data.msg)
      const namesArr = res.data.msg.map(user => user.school_name)
      setNames(namesArr)
      // return res.data.msg.map(user => user.school_name);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("ERROR");
      console.log(error);
    }).finally(() => setLoading(false))
}

<Autocomplete
            options={names}
            onOpen={() => getSchoolList()}
            loading={loading}
            sx={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="School Name" />}
          />
```

Comment: You assumed correctly. I tried useState([]) before but couldn't quite get it. This worked perfectly, thanks.